# "Group" and then Sorting

Tags: sql, sorting, oracle12c

I have a table like this:

```
ID | DocNumb  | RegistDate  | Adendun | DocOrigin | Status
1  | 01/2018  | 01/10/2018  | false   | null      | registered
2  | 02/2018  | 01/15/2018  | false   | null      | finished
3  | 01/2018  | 01/20/2018  | true    | 1         | finished
4  | 03/2018  | 01/25/2018  | false   | null      | registered
5  | 01/2018  | 01/30/2018  | true    | 1         | draft
6  | 02/2018  | 02/05/2018  | true    | 2         | registered
7  | 03/2018  | 02/10/2018  | true    | 4         | registered
8  | 03/2018  | 02/15/2018  | true    | 4         | finished
9  | 04/2018  | 02/20/2018  | false   | null      | draft
```

I must "group" the rows by the DocNumb before sorting by the Status column. I put group in quotes, because it's not really a grouping. What I need is to put the rows with the same DocNumb one bellow the other, sorted by the ResgitDate descending, then I must order those groups by the Status column of the most recent entry of each group alphabetically. The groups with the same Status must be sorted by the RegistDate of the most recent entry descending. This operation must give me the follow result:

```
ID | DocNumb  | RegistDate  | Adendun | DocOrigin | Status
9  | 04/2018  | 02/20/2018  | false   | null      | draft       <-most recent     
5  | 01/2018  | 01/30/2018  | true    | 1         | draft       <-most recent      
3  | 01/2018  | 01/20/2018  | true    | 1         | finished
1  | 01/2018  | 01/10/2018  | false   | null      | registered
8  | 03/2018  | 02/15/2018  | true    | 4         | finished    <-most recent      
7  | 03/2018  | 02/10/2018  | true    | 4         | registered
4  | 03/2018  | 01/25/2018  | false   | null      | registered
6  | 02/2018  | 02/05/2018  | true    | 2         | registered  <-most recent       
2  | 02/2018  | 01/15/2018  | false   | null      | finished
```

I managed to sort this in java code, but I wonder if there is a way of sorting like I explained via SQL. The actual table and it's relationships are more complex than this and I don't want to alter the original query much. I searched for this, but didn't find any examples. Sorry if it was already asked.

Edit: I need this because It's a report that print the results of a search. And the client wants that the report mimics the sort order of the result page. In the search results is only showed the most recent version of the docs, but the user can expand the row to see the previous versions. So in the report those versions should be next the most recent version in the report but not be considered in the sorting.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Order by DocNumb, Status ?

Comment: I don't see how your description matches the results.  Why is 03/2018 below 01?

Comment: To clarify, are "01/2018-A2", "01/2018-A1" and "01/2018" the same docnumb?

Comment: I added some columns to make things clear, or more confusing. 03 is bellow 01 because I need to sort by the status alphabetically, so the order is draft -> finished - registered. And I must only consider the most recent version of the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query meets your requirements:

```
   SELECT t.*
        , max(registDate)     OVER (PARTITION BY DocNumb)                          dmax
        , FIRST_VALUE(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNumb ORDER BY registDate DESC) stat
     FROM test t
 ORDER BY stat
        , dmax       desc
        , registDate desc
        ;
```

**Explanation**

- `PARTITION BY DocNumb` applies most recent date calculation and related ordering to each group of documents identifed by `DocNumb` in turn
- `FIRST_VALUE(Status)` delivers for each record in each group the first value of the status column given the group-local ordering by descending registration date
- The records from your table are then sorted by ...

  - ... the most recent document's status of a group
  - ... the most recent date among a group.
    This is needed to keep togehter the documents belonging to a group if there are several group with the same 'most recent status' and overlapping date ranges. (These conditions do not hold in your sample data)
  - ... and the registrration dates in descending order

**Demo**

See [this SQLFiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f31129/14).

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed. I will see if can update the query, because I already managed to sort via java code. I was curious if there was a way to do it in sql.

Answer (score 0):

First we associate the most recent date with the DocNumb

```
WITH DocDate AS
SELECT DocNumb, MAX(RegistDate) AS Date
FROM Table
GROUP BY DocNumb,
```

Then we find an order based on the relevant status

```
DocOrder AS   
SELECT S.DocNumb, ROW_NUMBER() AS rn
FROM Table AS S
JOIN DocDate AS D ON S.DocNumb = D.DocNumb AND S.RegistDate = D.RegistDate
ORDER BY S.Status DESC,
```

Then we apply the ordering

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM Table AS T
JOIN DocOrder AS O ON T.DocNumb = O.DocNumb
ORDER BY O.rn, T.RegisDate DESC
```

Comment: This throws syntax errors in oracle (in particular its `row_number() over (order by  S.Status desc`). After rectifying, the query does not produce the records in the order the OP desires.